# php call to store procedure with pdo issue

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I am wondering how I can call upon a store procedure with a in parameter in php code with pdo.

The way I would like to do this, is to display a select box loaded from the database, chose a value and then use that value as a in parameter for my store procedure.

First I have the sql for my select box:

```
$authorSql = "SELECT * FROM author"; 
$authorQuery = $pdo->prepare($authorSql); 
$authorQuery->execute();
```

then in my html:

```
<select name="authorid"> 
<?php

$authorid="";
while($author = $authorQuery->fetch()) { 
if ($author['id'] == $authorid) { 
//The author is currently associated to the joke, select it by default 
echo "<option value=\"{$author['id']}\" selected>{$author['name']}</option>"; 
} else { 
//The author is not currently associated to the joke 
echo "<option value=\"{$author['id']}\">{$author['name']}</option>"; 
} 
}

?> 
</select> 

<table width='80%' border=0>

    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <td>Joke</td>
        <td>Author Name</td>
        <td>Update</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
$result = $pdo->query("call jokes_author(:author)");       
    while($row = $result->fetch()) {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['joketext']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$row[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";        
    }

    ?>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </table>
```

The code for store procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `jokes_author`(IN author VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SELECT joke.joketext, author.name FROM author INNER JOIN joke ON author.id = joke.authorid where name = author;
END
```

The part I don't can't grasp is what to do to catch chosen value from the select box and pass into to call of store procedure.

-thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO in the following way:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("call jokes_author(:author)");       
$result->bindParam(':author', $author);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: thanks, but when I choose a value from the select box, nothing happens, does the $author variable from the select box pass in the value to the store procedure?

Comment: I just wrote the variable as an example. Pass the variable that contains the value of the parameter that you would pass in the stored procedure `jokes_author`. I'm guessing you'd pass the author id in it :)

Comment: normally it would be the name string that would be passed in, but I am confused of which variable to pass in to the store procedure

Comment: Pass $author['name']. If that doesn't work, you might as well try $author['id']

Comment: like this??
 $result = $pdo->prepare("call jokes_author(:author)");       
$result->bindParam(':author', $author['name']);
$result->execute();

Comment: The part of getting selected value from list, check here http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/48477-how-to-get-the-select-value-from-the-drop-down-list/

Comment: do you mean that I should the selecbox in a form with a submit button and check the value of submit?

Comment: That, or use jQuery/javascript to check the value of the selected option on the `onchange` event, and pass that in an ajax to your server and use that in the stored procedure.